# How to copy data from one collection to another existing collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a `coll-1` and `coll-2` in MongoDB. So, I need to copy data from `coll-1` to `coll-2` without disturbing collection data(both two collections are in same DB) and I don't want to do `mongoexport` and `mongoimport` because of these collection lots of data every time when we need to update little data I should be convenient.

Comment: what is your mongoDB version ?

Comment: [Take a look](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#comparison-with-merge) `$out` or `$merge` operators

Comment: You can try using `mongodump` and `mongorestore`. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59614419/mongodb-copy-unsharded-collection-into-sharded-ones/59628379#59628379

Comment: @srinivasy mongo version is 4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're on mongoDB V4.2 and your two collections are in same database and are existing, you need to use [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/index.html#examples) :

Try this query :

```
db.getCollection('coll-1').aggregate( [
   { $merge : { into: { coll: "coll-2" }, on: "_id",  whenNotMatched: "insert" } }
])
```

**Documents in col-1 :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1f7ac3f35652fb779fcf3e"),
    "random1" : 1
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1f7acff35652fb779fd310"),
    "random1" : 2
}
```

**Documents in col-2 :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1f7adcf35652fb779fdb42"),
    "random2" : 1
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1f7ae5f35652fb779fde24"),
    "random2" : 2
}
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1f7adcf35652fb779fdb42"),
    "random2" : 1
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1f7ae5f35652fb779fde24"),
    "random2" : 2
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1f7ac3f35652fb779fcf3e"),
    "random1" : 1
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1f7acff35652fb779fd310"),
    "random1" : 2
}
```

As I wanted to write everything in `coll-1` to `coll-2`, I don't have any stages in aggregation prior to `$merge`, You need to have this `$merge` as last stage in aggregation pipeline (For testing purpose you can actually remove it & validate the data through couple of dry runs & then execute the actual operation). Also `$merge` has a lot of options can be passed in few like - What to do if field values of `on` does match & few other options, So please go through the MongoDB documentation.

Comment: Instead of collection_id/name is there any option of input with JSON or CSV file? Please help me if any 
Now I am looking at I have a collection so I need to insert data from JSON/CSV but checking the duplications

Comment: @Nikhil : Then all you've to use is `mongoimport` !! You need to be specific with your question !! Do wanted to have a query to import from JSON ? What do you mean by duplications ?

Comment: I have large data files before importing to mongo I need to verify I am not inserting already existing document/data into the database again

thanks in advance

Comment: @Nikhil : Please raise a new question with all details, anyhow meanwhile when you say JSON files, So a does each document in JSON file has any unique field at least `_id` ? So that way you can actually have an unique field in `Coll-2` & insert data from JSON files, one operation is successful you can say everything went well with out any duplicates..